# Does std::equal_range require strict weak ordering?

Tags: c++, stl, partitioning

I see some documentation for older, non-standard equal_range that explicitly calls out a strict weak ordering (the old SGI docs) and some newer, standard equal_range that doesn't (cppreference, libstdc++ docs).

Was the function changed such that it used to require a strict weak ordering and now it requires... some sort of partition without a proper name?

Comment: The old SGI docs are docs for the STL, not for the C++ standard library. Similarly, the Boost docs are docs for Boost, not for the C++ standard library. They are of no relevance.

Comment: Thanks, edited question...

Comment: Yep better good stuff

Comment: This is a pretty good example of why we shouldn't confuse the STL and the C++ standard library, by the way.

Answer (score 4):

`std::equal_range` requires that the sequence being examined must be **partitioned** by the expressions `pr(value, N)` and `pr(N, value)` where `pr` is the predicate, `value` is the value for which you want to find the equal range and `N` is an element of the sequence.

For the sequence, that's a weaker condition than requiring that the sequence must be ordered with a strict weak ordering. It requires only that there is a partition point P, where `pr(N, value)` returns `true` for all elements N in the sequence prior to P, `pr(value, N)` returns `false` for all elements in the sequence at or after `P`. For example, the sequence [2, 1, 5, 4] is partitioned by `<` and the value `3`, the partitioning point being at the element with value 5.

For the predicate itself, `equal_range` requires asymmetry with respect to `value`, that is, `pr(N, value)` implies `! pr(value, N)` for all N of the sequence. In particular, this means that `pr(X, X)` can return `true`, which is not the case for a strict weak ordering. The requirements/properties for a strict weak ordering are:

- asymmetry: `pr(x, y)` implies `! pr(y, x)`
- irreflexivity: `pr(x, x) == false`
- transitivity: `pr(x, y) && pr(y, z)` implies `pr(x, z)`
- `! pr(x, y) && ! pr(y, z)` implies `! pr(x, z)` (in Elements of Programming, this is stated via an additional equivalence relation)

Note that these points apply for all elements x, y of the sequence. The requirement on `pr` in `equal_range` however is not a general requirement on the predicate, but a specific requirement for the predicate and that particular value.

Comment: "Partitioned by the predicate" might not be precise enough. As you state in your second paragraph, this is restricted to *the value* you pass to `equal_range`. E.g. [2, 1, 5, 4] is partitioned wrt `std::less<int>` and the value 3.

Comment: @dyp - I'm very tired, and my mind is getting all tangled up. So please feel free to edit my answer to fix that.

Comment: I might have gone overboard. Please review the changes.

Comment: There might be a defect in the spec: [2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4] is partitioned wrt `<` and 3, but it's pretty useless for `equal_range`. While `equal_range` simply does not guarantee that the result contains all occurrences of 3, I guess `upper_bound` has the same problem. EoP adds the requirement that the sequences/ranges must be (non-strictly) increasing. (Maybe it's not a defect, but these corner cases produce unexpected results.)

Comment: @dyp - I think your changes are fine. In fact, if you want to cut-and-paste this as your own answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @dyp - it just occurred to me that these requirements can probably be expressed informally as "the obvious implementation has to work".